# ASP.NET EF5 code-first not creating SQL Server CE database

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5

I searched far and wide, went through tutorials and tips, but it just wont work!

EF 5 code-first is not generating my SQL Server CE 4 database file.

I have an ASP.NET web application and I want to generate a database by using the code-first approach.

Here are my model classes:

```
    public class Class
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public bool isLecture { get; set; }

        public int courseId { get; set; }
        public virtual Course course { get; set; }
        public int teacherId { get; set; }
        public virtual Teacher teacher { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int semester { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the context:

```
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the connection string in `web.config`:

```
    <add name="MyContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyContext.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

This is in `global.asax.cs`:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>
            (new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());

        ...
    }
```

I've tried w/ and w/o these lines in `global.asax.cs` and w/ and w/o the connection string.

The application loads and works, but the database file just isn't created. I tried creating the `.sdf` file myself, so it could be populated by EF code-first, but it remains empty.

The project is ASP.NET MVC 4 made with HotTowel template, if it means anything, and I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

**SOLVED:**

Needed this code in `global.asax.cs`:

```
    MyContext context = new MyContext();
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me - you need the connection factory...

```
<configSections>...
</configSections>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory 
        type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: Still no database file. Under Data Connections, Server Explorer has a broken link to MyContex.sdf, and when I try to open it, it says:
`The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = c:\...path...\MyProject\SekretarskiModul\App_Data\MyContext.sdf ]`